# c# RoleProvider login with specific role

Tags: c#, roleprovider, role

I try to implement a login for my application.
The user can have multiple roles (Viewer, Operator, Admin etc.).
But he has to choose a certain role that with which he wants to get logged in,
so he probably has administratior prviliges but he can login as a "Viewer" with no admin rights.

The problem is now that if I try to secure some functions with the RequiredRole attribute for an administrator, the user should not be able to access this function if he is logged in as viewer, even if he would have administrator rights.

Is such a beaviour supported from the framework or has anyone done something similar before?

Thanks anyway for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've not specified what you want to happen when he tries to do something that requires Admin when he's logged in as Viewer, but since you can implement your own Role Provider, this is easy to do.

You should be able to store something in the session or your user principal object stating the "available roles" (some of them won't be able to pick Administrator, for example) and then another one for Selected Role.  All you'd need to do is put some page into your site to allow the user to select their current role.

Since you'd be using your own Role Provider, you can just implement this to pull the relevant information out of the Session (or the User Principal) when checking roles.  You'll still be able to use the RequiredRole attribute as you like.

There are a few examples around of how you can change the behaviour from redirecting you to the logon form when you don't have access to redirect you to a 403 page (e.g. [With ASP.NET membership, how can I show a 403?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1847099/with-asp-net-membership-how-can-i-show-a-403)).  You could then show something on this page which would allow the user to switch to a higher role if they have one available.

Comment: hi, thanks for your fast response :)
so on client side i can acces the user object with:
WebContext.Current.User

This custom user object has the two properties CurrentRole and AvailableRoles. The login where the use can select his role is also already implement, but now I don't know how to access this CurrentRole in my RoleProvider to adapt my GetRolesForUser method, which I think should just return this current role? Or do i have to adapt the IsUserInRole method?

Thanks for your help =)

Comment: You'll need to implement `IsUserInRole`, and probably `GetRolesForUser`.  From both of these you should be able to access `HttpContext.Current`, and from there you have access to the User and Session objects.  This should be all you'd need.  GetRolesForUser should only return the "Current" role.

Comment: Hi again, thanks, i tried it now this way...in my opinion it should work...but i ran into an exception now:
as mentioned, we have a custom user object to store these additional information like current role
when i try now to access HttpContext.Current.User it is from type IPrincipal while WebContext.Current.User is our custom object, so i'm not able to access the needed information =/
I think if I would get this information my problem would be solved...

Comment: See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthenticationeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx) for how to provide a custom principal object.  You'll still need to cast it back from `IPrincipal` to your customised type though.

Comment: Hi again, so I had a look at your link
Because I did not write the login part myself and I'm new to the whole web development I'm a bit confused :)
So how (and where) do I write this FormsAuthentication_OnAuthenticate method? Do I have to change basic things in my current login implementation?
So in my App.xaml it creates a new WebContext and within a new Authentication: 
WebContext webContext = new WebContext  // create RIA webcontext
         {
            Authentication = new FormsAuthentication(),
         };
How do I get this OnAuthenticate Event now?

Thank you for your help again :)

Comment: I don't know if RIA is any different, but you can also do this in Application_OnAuthenticate in global.asax.

Comment: Hi, I will look for a solution with my coworker who wrote the most things for this login, he has some more experience with these things :)
but anyway thank you for your help =)